# Счётчик правильных и неправильных ответов

Tags: python, интерфейс

Хочу создать викторину в виде интерфейса. Вроде бы все сделано, но не знаю как добавить счётчик правильных ответов, который будет показываться снизу и в messagebox в самом конце. Код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title('Викторина')
root.geometry('600x600')
root["bg"] = "#FFD700"

correctCount = 0
incorrectCount = 0

def que_one():
    question = Label(root, text='Тут будет вопрос', font='20', fg='#000000', bg='#FFE4B5')
    question_2 = Label(root, text='Введи ответ цифрой: ', font='15', fg='#000000')
    answer = Entry(bg='#C0C0C0')
    btn = Button(root, text='Ответить', command=lambda: game1(que_two))
    btn.grid(row = 0)
    btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3 = Label(root, text='1. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_4 = Label(root, text='2. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_5 = Label(root, text='3. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_6 = Label(root, text='Правильных ответов: 0', font='5', bg='#FFD700')
    question_6.place(relx=.2, rely=.9, anchor="c", height=25, width=200, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question.grid(row = 0)
    question.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_2.place(relx=.5, rely=.6, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    answer.grid(row = 1)
    answer.place(relx=.5, rely=.7, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3.grid(row = 1)
    question_3.place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_4.grid(row = 1)
    question_4.place(relx=.5, rely=.3, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_5.grid(row = 1)
    question_5.place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

    def game1(que_two):
        if answer.get().lower() == '1':
            correctCount = correctCount + 1
            que_two()
        else:
            incorrectCount = incorrectCount +1
            que_two()


def que_two():
    question = Label(root, text='Тут будет вопрос', font='20', fg='#000000', bg='#FFE4B5')
    question_2 = Label(root, text='Введи ответ цифрой: ', font='15', fg='#000000')
    answer = Entry(bg='#C0C0C0')
    btn_1 = Button(root, text='Ответить', command=lambda: game2(que_two))
    btn_1.grid(row = 0)
    btn_1.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3 = Label(root, text='1. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_4 = Label(root, text='2. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_5 = Label(root, text='3. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question.grid(row = 0)
    question.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_2.place(relx=.5, rely=.6, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    answer.grid(row = 1)
    answer.place(relx=.5, rely=.7, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3.grid(row = 1)
    question_3.place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_4.grid(row = 1)
    question_4.place(relx=.5, rely=.3, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_5.grid(row = 1)
    question_5.place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

    def game2(que_two):
        if answer.get().lower() == '2':
            que_three();
            correctCount = correctCount + 1
        else:
            que_three();
            incorrectCount = incorrectCount +1

def que_three():
    question = Label(root, text='Тут будет вопрос', font='20', fg='#000000', bg='#FFE4B5')
    question_2 = Label(root, text='Введи ответ цифрой: ', font='15', fg='#000000')
    answer = Entry(bg='#C0C0C0')
    btn_1 = Button(root, text='Ответить', command=lambda: game3(que_two))
    btn_1.grid(row = 0)
    btn_1.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3 = Label(root, text='1. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_4 = Label(root, text='2. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_5 = Label(root, text='3. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question.grid(row = 0)
    question.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_2.place(relx=.5, rely=.6, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    answer.grid(row = 1)
    answer.place(relx=.5, rely=.7, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3.grid(row = 1)
    question_3.place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_4.grid(row = 1)
    question_4.place(relx=.5, rely=.3, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_5.grid(row = 1)
    question_5.place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

    def game3(que_two):
        if answer.get().lower() == '2':
            correctCount = correctCount + 1 
            messagebox.showinfo('Правильных ответов: ' + str(correctCount))
        else:
            incorrectCount = incorrectCount +1
            messagebox.showinfo('Правильных ответов: ' + str(correctCount))


que_one()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такой вариант кода (хотя его можно еще лучше оптимизировать):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title('Викторина')
root.geometry('600x600')
root["bg"] = "#FFD700"

correctCount = 0
incorrectCount = 0
answer_counter = Label(root, text='Правильных ответов: 0', font='5', bg='#FFD700')
answer_counter.place(relx=.2, rely=.9, anchor="c", height=25, width=200, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

def create_field(root, question, answer1, answer2, answer3):
    Label(root, text=question, font='20', fg='#000000', bg='#FFE4B5').place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE) #поле с вопросом
    Label(root, text='Введи ответ цифрой: ', font='15', fg='#000000').place(relx=.5, rely=.6, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    Label(root, text=f'1. {answer1}', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF').place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE) # поле с ответом 1
    Label(root, text=f'2. {answer2}', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF').place(relx=.5, rely=.3, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE) # поле с ответом 2
    Label(root, text=f'3. {answer3}', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF').place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE) # поле с ответом 3
    answer = Entry(bg='#C0C0C0')
    answer.place(relx=.5, rely=.7, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    return answer

def que_one():
    answer=create_field(root, 'Вопрос', 'Ответ1', 'Ответ2', 'Ответ3')
    Button(root, text='Ответить', command=lambda: game1()).place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE) # кнопка ответить
    def game1():
        global correctCount, incorrectCount, answer_counter
        if answer.get().lower() == '1':
            correctCount = correctCount + 1
        else:
            incorrectCount = incorrectCount +1
        answer_counter['text']=f'Правильных ответов: {correctCount}'
        que_two()


def que_two():
    answer=create_field(root, 'Вопрос', 'Ответ1', 'Ответ2', 'Ответ3')
    Button(root, text='Ответить', command=lambda: game2()).place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE) # кнопка ответить

    def game2():
        global correctCount, incorrectCount, answer_counter
        if answer.get().lower() == '2':
            correctCount = correctCount + 1
        else:
            incorrectCount = incorrectCount +1
        answer_counter['text']=f'Правильных ответов: {correctCount}'
        que_three()

def que_three():
    answer=create_field(root, 'Вопрос', 'Ответ1', 'Ответ2', 'Ответ3')
    Button(root, text='Ответить', command=lambda: game3()).place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE) # кнопка ответить

    def game3():
        global correctCount, incorrectCount
        if answer.get().lower() == '2':
            correctCount = correctCount + 1
        else:
            incorrectCount = incorrectCount +1
        messagebox.showinfo('Результат викторины','Правильных ответов: ' + str(correctCount))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    que_one()
    root.mainloop()
```

Либо такой вариант, ближе к вашему:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title('Викторина')
root.geometry('600x600')
root["bg"] = "#FFD700"

correctCount = 0
incorrectCount = 0
answer_counter = Label(root, text='Правильных ответов: 0', font='5', bg='#FFD700')
answer_counter.place(relx=.2, rely=.9, anchor="c", height=25, width=200, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

def que_one():
    question = Label(root, text='Тут будет вопрос', font='20', fg='#000000', bg='#FFE4B5')
    question_2 = Label(root, text='Введи ответ цифрой: ', font='15', fg='#000000')
    answer = Entry(bg='#C0C0C0')
    btn = Button(root, text='Ответить', command=lambda: game1())
    btn.grid(row = 0)
    btn.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3 = Label(root, text='1. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_4 = Label(root, text='2. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_5 = Label(root, text='3. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question.grid(row = 0)
    question.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_2.place(relx=.5, rely=.6, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    answer.grid(row = 1)
    answer.place(relx=.5, rely=.7, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3.grid(row = 1)
    question_3.place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_4.grid(row = 1)
    question_4.place(relx=.5, rely=.3, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_5.grid(row = 1)
    question_5.place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

    def game1():
        global correctCount, incorrectCount
        if answer.get().lower() == '1':
            correctCount += 1
        else:
            incorrectCount += 1
        answer_counter['text']=f'Правильных ответов: {correctCount}'
        que_two()


def que_two():
    question = Label(root, text='Тут будет вопрос', font='20', fg='#000000', bg='#FFE4B5')
    question_2 = Label(root, text='Введи ответ цифрой: ', font='15', fg='#000000')
    answer = Entry(bg='#C0C0C0')
    btn_1 = Button(root, text='Ответить', command=lambda: game2())
    btn_1.grid(row = 0)
    btn_1.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3 = Label(root, text='1. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_4 = Label(root, text='2. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_5 = Label(root, text='3. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question.grid(row = 0)
    question.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_2.place(relx=.5, rely=.6, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    answer.grid(row = 1)
    answer.place(relx=.5, rely=.7, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3.grid(row = 1)
    question_3.place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_4.grid(row = 1)
    question_4.place(relx=.5, rely=.3, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_5.grid(row = 1)
    question_5.place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

    def game2():
        global correctCount, incorrectCount
        if answer.get().lower() == '2':
            correctCount +=1
        else:
            incorrectCount += 1
        answer_counter['text']=f'Правильных ответов: {correctCount}'
        que_three()


def que_three():
    question = Label(root, text='Тут будет вопрос', font='20', fg='#000000', bg='#FFE4B5')
    question_2 = Label(root, text='Введи ответ цифрой: ', font='15', fg='#000000')
    answer = Entry(bg='#C0C0C0')
    btn_1 = Button(root, text='Ответить', command=lambda: game3())
    btn_1.grid(row = 0)
    btn_1.place(relx=.5, rely=.8, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3 = Label(root, text='1. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_4 = Label(root, text='2. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question_5 = Label(root, text='3. Тут будет ответ', font='15', bg='#DC143C', fg='#FFFFFF')
    question.grid(row = 0)
    question.place(relx=.5, rely=.1, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_2.place(relx=.5, rely=.6, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    answer.grid(row = 1)
    answer.place(relx=.5, rely=.7, anchor="c", height=30, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_3.grid(row = 1)
    question_3.place(relx=.5, rely=.2, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_4.grid(row = 1)
    question_4.place(relx=.5, rely=.3, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)
    question_5.grid(row = 1)
    question_5.place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c", height=50, width=500, bordermode=OUTSIDE)

    def game3():
        global correctCount, incorrectCount
        if answer.get().lower() == '2':
            correctCount += 1
        else:
            incorrectCount += 1
        messagebox.showinfo('Результат викторины', 'Правильных ответов: ' + str(correctCount))


que_one()

root.mainloop()
```